# Transporting a desktop computer and LCD monitor

Tags: display, desktop-computer, transporting

I've got a friend who's relocating to another country for work, and he's asked me to help pack his computers. In addition to a bunch of laptops (and their accessories), he's got a single desktop PC tower and an 18" LCD monitor. The laptops are easy enough to handle, but what about the tower? He just happens to have the original boxes for both the case and monitor, so could I just stuff them into the boxes with some old clothes on the sides for padding? Bear in mind he's not going to be shipping this separately, he wants to bring it on as checked baggage on the plane.

Assuming that he could do that (and I really don't see any reason why he couldn't), what sort of precautions would I need to take? Do I need to do anything special to secure things like the HD and any expansion cards like his GTX550 ti? I've heard that the heat sink can damage the mobo in transit, is this true?

Comment: Nor quite a dupe, but this is worth looking at since it covers the [same basic scenario](http://superuser.com/questions/253709/concerns-about-shipping-a-pc-if-i-move-abroad/253726#253726)

Answer (score 1):

Remove anything heavy like coolers (and graphics cards with coolers) as the physical force from vibrations and shock during transport could damage the slots and mounts of those heavy parts.

Also make sure to remove disks and transport them seperatly to avoid damaging vibrations being transferred from the case.

Comment: Even the CPU cooler? He's using the stock cooler, not some 3rd party one, and it doesn't seem all that heavy. Would it be safe to leave it attached to the mobo? It would spare us the trouble of having to pack thermal paste to re-attach it once he lands.